# ¿Cómo comparar el resultado consulta mysql con o otra variable?

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Tengo una variable `$dayname = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)));` y otra de tipo String `$dianombre = '';`

Lo que estoy buscando es comparar $dayname con el valor de $dianombre. y lo hago asi
si "harcodeo" el valor de  $dianombre y le asigno un dia quedando  `$dianombre = 'monday'` y lo comparo con con $dayname:

```
if($dayname == $dianombre ){

             $fecha.="<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>NO DISPONIBLE</button>";
```

Funciona y mi boton cambia. Pero si en vez de "harcodear" el valor de $dianombre traigo ese valor desde una Bd Mysql no funciona.

Estoy haciendo un bucle while para iterar la sentencia sql asi:

```
$datos= array();
$dianombre = '';


if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 ) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

        $datos[] = $row;


      }//fin del if de la conexion


   } //fin de if


$dianombre = datos;
```

Si le hago un print_r a $dianombre me muestra:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dausente1] => saturday ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [dausente1] => saturday ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [dausente1] => saturday ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [dausente1] => saturday ) )
```

Y cuando hago la comparación:

```
if($dayname == $dianombre[0]){
    $fecha.="<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>NO DISPONIBLE</button>";
```

NO FUNCIONA.
He probado cambiar $dianombre a tipo array ya que lo que recibe de la consulta es un array y tampoco funciona.Quiza el problema esté en como llamo al valor de de $dianombre o en el While. He cambiado a mysqli_fetch_array y tampoco funciona.  No sé que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

he solucionado el problema de esta manera:

```
$vector = [];


array_walk_recursive($datos, function($datos) use (&$vector) {


  $vector[] = $datos;
});
```